# How to use Inner Join and Except in Linq EntityFramework 4

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have two tables with a one (Parent) to many (Details) relationship.

I would like to write this query (which is written in SQL) in Linq. As you see; it is an inner join on a subquery, which contains Except:

```
select pa.* from dbo.Parent pa
inner join
(
      select    p.ID  from dbo.Parent p
          except
               (
                  select  d.ID from dbo.Details d  where (d.ParentID = 371)
               )
) p
on pa.ID = p.ID
where pa.ID <> 371
```

Comment: LINQPad is perfect for something like this.

Comment: this is a really bad sql query, and you've asked us to make a really bad linq query... the sub query is very dubious, try to refactor it using just joins and where clauses.  at that point, your linq query should make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Parent.Where(p=>Details.Where(d=>d.ParentID!=371)
                                    .Select(d=>d.ID)
                                    .Contains(p.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

king king is probably on the right path but here's one using a join,

```
parent.Join(Details , 
        parent => parent.Id,
        detail => detail.Id,
        (parent, detail) => new { P = parent, D = detail)
        .Where(e => e.D.ParentId != 371)
        .Select(e => e.P);
```